# How do you create a QPushButton in the MainWindow?

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, mainwindow

```
QPushButton* m_button = new QPushButton();
```

Whenever i try to create a `QPushButton` like this, it appears to be created in a new separate window. However, I want the Button to be created within the Mainwindow but I don't know how to do this (without using the Qt Designer).

Comment: It depends on what do you actually want to achieve. The simplest way is just adding a button to the main window like: `setCentralWidget(m_button);`, assuming that you call that function from main window class.

Comment: QPushButton* m_button = new QPushButton(this);

Comment: The setCentralWidget Method worked out fine. Thanks a lot, vahancho!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the MainWindow as a parent

try this:

```
QPushButton* m_button = new QPushButton(this)
```

Comment: When I try your Code, I receive the error: "no matching constructor for initialization of 'QPushButton'

Comment: `this` must refer to a QWidget. Since QMainWindow is derived by QWidget, it should work

Comment: My code looks like this:
MainwindowInstance{
public:
MainwindowInstance();
MainWindow w;
}
When I try to create a QPushButton in my MainWindow from another class by the following code, the Button is always opened in another window.
MainwindowInstance* instance = new MainwindowInstance();
QPushButton *m_button = new QPushButton(&instance->w);
Any further advice?